# getting the row name of which.max when doing summarise in ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I have the following data and want to get the dates when Close is at its max for each Year.

```
> str(ndvdf)
'data.frame':   1374 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Close: num  150 150 150 150 150 ...
 $ Year : num  2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 ...
> head(ndvdf)
            Close Year
2010-01-04 150.34 2009
2010-01-05 150.34 2009
2010-01-06 150.34 2009
```

I tried the following but the row indices are return rather than dates and the indices are for each yearly subsets so it's difficult to use rownames to get the dates either.

```
> ddply(ndvdf, .(Year), summarise, MaxDate=which.max(Close))
  Year MaxDate
1 2009      60
2 2010     244
3 2011     245
```

How can I get the dates from my data?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some reproducible sample data:

```
set.seed(19)
df <- data.frame(Close = sample(150, 10), Year = sample(2000:2003, 10, TRUE))
rownames(df) <- Sys.Date() + 1:10
```

I prefer to use the *data.table* package here.  We can use `as.data.table` with `keep.rownames = TRUE` and use that to easily get the row names (dates) for when "Close" is at its max for each "Year".

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)[, rn[which.max(Close)], keyby = Year]
#    Year         V1
# 1: 2000 2015-08-13
# 2: 2001 2015-08-17
# 3: 2002 2015-08-16
# 4: 2003 2015-08-18
```